# Prove that any element of vector space $V \otimes W$ can be represented as $\sum \limits_{i=0}^{r}v_i \otimes w_i$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, tensor-products

How to prove that any element of tensor product can be represented as 
$\sum \limits_{i=0}^{r}v_i \otimes w_i$, where vectors $v_1,\ldots,v_r \in V$ and vectors $w_1, \ldots w_r \in W$ are linear independent.

Comment: Also answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2184389/tensor-product-simple-tensors?noredirect=1&lq=1).