# Tensor product. Simple tensors.

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, tensors

I have the following problem in my assignment:

Prove that every element of $V \otimes W$ can be represented as $\sum \limits_{i = 1}^{k} v_i \otimes w_i$, where $v_i$ are linearly independent and $w_i$ are linearly independent.

I thought that we can do the following:
Every tensor can be written as a linear combination of basis vectors $e_i \otimes f_j$, so we can represent this tensor as sum: $\sum \limits_{i = 1}^{n} e_i \otimes w_i$ (using tensor and summation properties). So, I have similar representation, but second components might be linearly dependent. My question is am I thinking in the right direction, and if so how I can transform this representation to make vectors in second component linearly independent?

Comment: try considering an expression $\sum_{i=1}^k v_i \otimes w_i$ with $k$ as small as possible. Could there be a linear dependence amongst the $v_i$?

Comment: @m_t_ For $k = 1$ obviously no. For $k = 2$ also no, because if $v_1 = kv_2$ we can rewrite our sum $v_1 \otimes w_1 + v_2 \otimes w_2 = kv_2 \otimes w_1 + v_2 \otimes w_2 = v_2 \otimes (kw_1 + w_2)$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given an element $\alpha \in V \otimes W$, we know it can be written as $\sum_{i=1}^k v_i \otimes w_i$ for some $v_i \in V, w_i \in W$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Consider such a presentation of $\alpha$ in which $k$ is minimal. Let us show that in such a presentation, the vectors $v_1,\dots,v_k$ must be linearly independent and similarly the vectors $w_1,\dots,w_k$ must be linearly independent.

If $v_1,\dots,v_k$ are linearly dependent then without loss of generality (by reordering the $(v_i,w_i)$) we can assume that $v_1 = \sum_{i=2}^k a_i v_i$ for some $a_2,\dots,a_k$. But then

$$ \alpha = \sum_{i=1}^k v_i \otimes w_i = v_1 \otimes w_1 + \sum_{i=2}^k v_i \otimes w_i = \left( \sum_{i=2}^k a_i v_i \right) \otimes w_1 + \sum_{i=2}^k v_i \otimes w_i \\
= \sum_{i=2}^k a_i (v_i \otimes w_1) + \sum_{i=2}^k v_i \otimes w_i = \sum_{i=2}^k v_i \otimes (a_i w_1) + \sum_{i=2}^k v_i \otimes w_i = \sum_{i=2}^k v_i \otimes (w_i + a_i w_1)$$

contradicting the minimality of $k$. The argument for the independent of the $(w_i)_{i=1}^k$ is exactly the same.

Comment: @Integral: Yep, thanks.

Comment: No problem. And sorry for I just deleted my comment.

Comment: I can't use this argument for a general tensor $\alpha \in V_1 \otimes \ldots \otimes V_k$. Do you know how to generalize? Thank you.

Comment: I will elaborate more and make a question. Just a few moments and I'll put a link here.

Comment: Here is the link, if you are interested. Thanks. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2449325/tensor-product-and-linear-dependence-of-vectors